# GNOME Shell crashing on enabling Extensons from GNOME Tweak Tool on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, crash, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. 
Everything is working fine except the Extensions.

I tried enabling them using GNOME Tweaks Tool

Tweak tools -> Extensions Sidebar -> Top right corner
[image: GNOME Tweaks Tools]

But as soon as I toggle that, the shell crashes and I see this screen.
[image: Shell Crashes]

I am forced to logout and then login again. And then extensions are disabled again.

I tried enabling them even through **dconf Editior** but the same thing happens. The shell crashes immediately.

I tried looking for solutions but it seems like the issue is experienced by extremely few people. I could only find one question for it on Reddit (no solutions on it yet).

Does anyone know what the issue is about and if there is a fix for it? I am not able to use extensions and this is really bothering me. I am ready to provide any further details necessary to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to incompatibility of some extension(s) with the current version. It seems as soon as you're enabling extensions, the incompatible extension(s) is/are causing the crash.

To fix it you remove all the extensions and then manually reinstall them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an issue with the extensions, but with GNOME Shell. I am on Arch and `gnome-shell-1.3.38`, which is the latest update, has the same issue on my laptop. Downgrading it makes it work fine with all other extensions. There have been two upgrades since I first noticed it and I still see the issue.